# Error in running Xpath in MarkLogic Data Hub Harmonization header plugin

Tags: javascript, xpath, marklogic

I am trying to use XPath in the MarkLogic Data Hub header. The goal is to get a Property2 element value from an XML document *(content)* (see sample below)

```
<instance>
<info xmlns="">
   <title>Entity</title>
   <version>0.0.1</version>
 </info>
<Entity xmlns="">
    <Property1>100533</Property1>
    <Property2>130008HU46</Property2>
    <Property3>Z1-Electrico</Property3>
</Entity>
```

Below is the code for the header plugin in my harmonization flow:

```js
 'use strict'
 /*
 * Create Headers Plugin
 *
 * @param id       - the identifier returned by the collector
 * @param content  - the output of your content plugin
 * @param options  - an object containing options. Options are sent from Java
 *
 * @return - an object of headers
 */
 var he = require("/lib/hierarchyEditLib.sjs");
 var hd = require("/lib/headerLib.sjs");

 function createHeaders(id, content, options) {

 let ctx = createContext(content);  
 let guid = hd.generateUUID()

 return {
  "guid": guid,
  "sourceURI": id,
  "context" : ctx
     }
 }

 function createContext(content)
 {
 let header = {};
  
 header.BusinessUnit = content.xpath('//*:' + "Property2" + '/string()').toString();

 header.DateOfHarmonization =  fn.replace(fn.substring(fn.string(fn.currentDateTime()),1,10), "-", "/");
 header.TimeOfHarmonization = fn.string(fn.currentTime());
   
 return header;  
 }

 module.exports = {
 createHeaders: createHeaders
 };
```

Everytime I run the flow, I am always seeing an error below in the traces:

> **JS-JAVASCRIPT: header.BusinessUnit = content.xpath('//*:' + "Property2" + '/string()').toString(); -- Error running JavaScript request: TypeError: content.xpath is not a function**

Is there any reference I'm missing or is there something wrong / insufficient in my current logic?

Comment: What is content.xpath() ? For applying xpath to xml we use `evaluate`.

Comment: Content is the XML document. My goal for using content.xpath is to get the node value of Property2 element in mark logic javascript API

Comment: @derloopkat xpath is a method on Node and all of its "subtypes" and is the appropriate way to address substructures of an XML node from Sever-Side Javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which version of DHF is this for? If it's 2.x then there's a bit of translation going on in the backend that is actually passing things as objects and maps in the background. 3.0 handles things more natively, and this translation doesn't occur.

So when you are running this, you're actually translating the xml document into a map:map in the background, then passing that value back into the javascript engine (V8) which interprets it as a type Object (a sequence of key:values, which the mirror in xquery to the map).

So, you can resolve this a few ways: one of the ways would be to simply fn.head(content) and then dot-notion identify properties off it:

```
let contentObj = fn.head(content);
header.BusinessUnit = contentObj.Property2;
```

This should return what you're expecting. If you need to dynamically swap what the property will be, contentObj['Property2'] should also work for you.

We've identified this is intuitive when working with javascript and xml in DHF, so in the next release, we will be moving to treating all documents (whether xml or json) as Nodes in server-side javascript. This means they will be passed as ObjectNode, so you can do dot-notion OR xpath against them raw out of the box.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried your suggestion. I followed your code suggestion. After execution, no error is found but upon checking but the header.BusinessUnit doesn't contain any values. I added conditional statement to check the value.

Comment: I'd suspect you aren't actually getting the content. xdmp.log(content) and check your error log on port 8011, and see if the content is what you're expecting.

I suspect the content plugin isn't giving you what you believe it to be.

Comment: T fn.head(content) is now returning value but it is not what I am expecting.                                       <info xmlns="">
   <title>Entity</title>
   <version>0.0.1</version>
 </info>

Answer (score 0):

The .xpath method is only available on Documents. Most likely, `content` in your case is not a Document. You can check with [xdmp.nodeKind](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp.nodeKind)

Comment: I see. This content contains an XML document which is the output from the "Content" logic and is being the input for the header in data hub

Comment: My best guess is that you have a Sequence in hand, rather than just a document. fn.doc, for example, returns a Sequence. You can probe the type with an expression such as: Object.prototype.toString.call(content). If it is a Sequence, use fn.head(content).xpath(...).

Comment: @kcoleman I tried the Object.prototype.toString.call and found out it was [object Sequence] type. Since it is a sequence, I used the fn.head(doc).xpath('//*:' + "Property2" + '/string()').toString() but is not getting any values. For some reason, I am able to get the Property2 element value when I execute the code in the Query Console.

Comment: @Ryan Did you confirm that fn.head(doc) is returning what you expect?

Comment: @kcoleman yet is returning what I expect when I execute the code in Query console but I'm not getting any value when I execute the code in the header during harmonization

Comment: But you need to check what it is during harmonization, not in QC. I'd try something like what Alex suggested above: xdmp.log(content) or xdmp.log(fn.head(content)) (or both), and then see what ends up in the log.

Comment: @kcoleman fn.head is only returning the first sub sequence of content XML. However, Using  fn.subsequence(content, 2) I was able to get the 2nd sequence. Now how do I iterate to get the Property2 value from subsequence below?                                  
  <Entity xmlns="">
    <Property1>100533</Property1>
    <Property2>130008HU46</Property2>
    <Property3>Z1-Electrico</Property3>
</Entity>

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. A Sequence is a JavaScript Iterable, so you can iterate over it in the usual ways. See http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/jsref/api#id_59096.

Comment: Thanks for the response @kcoleman! Do you have any example code snippet on how to implement a Sequence in javascript? Thanks!